# Shape Drawing GUI. Using paintComponent with a class derived from JPanel.

Tags: user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

I'm trying to draw a simple gui in which a user adds data and then you press a button and it draws the shape in the window.  I failed on the larger program, so I'm back to square one.  I'm just trying to create a simple window that has a "Draw" button in the menu bar.  When you press the button, a shape, which I have hardcoded into a class derived from JPanel that implements the graphics class, should appear in the same window.

Here's what I have, but it's not working.  Can someone please see what I'm doing wrong.  The frustrating part is that when I just create the shape and add it to the layout in the constructor, it works fine, but when I try to use a button to perform the operation, it fails.

Thanks.

public class ShapeGUITest extends JFrame {

```
public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
public static final int X = 100;
public static final int Y = 75;
public static final int SHAPE_BASE = 200;
public static final int SHAPE_HEIGHT = 250;
JPanel buttonPanel;
JComponent shapeArea;

public ShapeGUITest() {

    super("Draw Shapes Dammit!");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    shapeArea = new Jpanel();
    add(shapeArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw");
    drawButton.addActionListener(new DrawButtonListener());

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    bar.add(drawButton);
    setJMenuBar(bar);

}

/*public void drawShapePanel() {
    shapeArea = new ShapePanel();
    add(shapeArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}*/

private class DrawButtonListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //drawShapePanel();

    //shapeArea = new ShapePanel();
    //add(shapeArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ShapePanel s = new ShapePanel();
    //s.setVisible(true);
    //shapeArea.removeAll();
    shapeArea.add(s);
    shapeArea.revalidate();
    validate();
    //ShapeFrame s = new ShapeFrame();

}
}

private class ShapeFrame extends JFrame {

    public ShapeFrame() {
        super("the shape is here");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(X, Y, SHAPE_BASE, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(X, Y, SHAPE_BASE, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
    }
}

private class ShapePanel extends JPanel {

    public ShapePanel() {
        super();
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(X, Y, SHAPE_BASE, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(X, Y, SHAPE_BASE, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShapeGUITest gui = new ShapeGUITest();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

}